# how can i display image in a gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here in code In this code i can update image in folder path but image file name cannot save in the database for this reason, i think my image is not show the gridview 
plz help me

```
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:FileUpload ID="photoTextBox" runat="server" filename='<%# Bind("photo")%>.jpg' />                                   
</EditItemTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>    
<img alt="" src="ImageStorage/<%# Eval("personalid") %>.jpg" width="40" height="40" id="image1" />
<asp:Label ID="photoLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# String.Concat(Eval("personalid"),".jpg")%>' ></asp:Label>                                 
</ItemTemplate>
```

C#

```
 protected void RadGrid4_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Update")
        {
            GridEditableItem eitem = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
            FileUpload photoTextBox = eitem.FindControl("photoTextBox") as FileUpload;
            TextBox personalidTextBox = eitem.FindControl("personalidTextBox") as TextBox;
            Label photoLabel = eitem.FindControl("photoLabel") as Label;

            string filename = Path.GetFileName(personalidTextBox.Text + ".jpg");           

            photoTextBox.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("ImageStorage/" + filename));
          }
     }
```

Comment: have you tried accessing one of the images using "url/ImageStorage/{sampleid}.jpg" in the browser? If it shows the image, check the source of the HTML generated on the client side to see if the image src generated correctly..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problems is with the databinding. As we have only few lines of code so cant figure out the actual issue. But as far as I can see the binding is not upto the marks. Assuming ImagePath is the db column try changing the aspx as per below:

ASPX

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:FileUpload 
         ID="photoTextBox" 
         runat="server" />                                  
</EditItemTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>    
<img alt="" 
     src='<%#Eval("ImagePath")%>' 
     width="40" 
     height="40" 
     id="image1" />

<asp:Label 
     ID="photoLabel" 
     runat="server" 
     Text='<%#String.Concat(Eval("personalid"),".jpg")%>' >
</asp:Label>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void RadGrid4_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Update")
        {
            GridEditableItem eitem = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
            FileUpload photoTextBox = eitem.FindControl("photoTextBox") as FileUpload;
            TextBox personalidTextBox = eitem.FindControl("personalidTextBox") as TextBox;
            Label photoLabel = eitem.FindControl("photoLabel") as Label;

            string filename = String.Format("{0}.jpg",personalidTextBox.Text);           
            string uploadPath = string.Format("~/ImageStorage/{0}",fileName)
            photoTextBox.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(uploadPath));
            ViewState["UploadPath"]=uploadPath;
            // use the above viewstate path to save in db in gridview rowupdating event and bind the grid again
          }
 }
```

Comment: it's show me error Failed to map the path '/ImageStorage/395.jpg'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code on upload button click event.

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   // Specify the path on the server to
   // save the uploaded file to.
   String savePath = @"c:\temp\uploads\";

   if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
   {
     String fileName = FileUpload1.FileName;
     savePath += fileName;
     FileUpload1.SaveAs(savePath);
   }
  }
```

Also remove the extension from `filename='<%# Bind("photo")%>.jpg'` that is `filename='<%# Bind("photo")%>'`. When we upload a file, its extension is automatically saved.

Answer (score 0):

to upload the images use the code as explained by @Aayushi Jain. and to bind that image to grid view you need to use `ResolveUrl`. For that you need to take `ImageField` in the gridview.